# Assign hidden value using Struts2 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

How assign the hidden value using Struts tag inside of iteration.
My JSP code looks like this:

```
<s:iterator value="collegelist">
    <s:hidden name="hiddenname" value='<s:property value="collegename"/>'/>
</s:iterator>
```

It takes hidden field's value as a string it show on alert:

```
<s:property value="collegename"/>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var text = myForm.hiddenname.value;
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<s:iterator value="list">
  <s:hidden name="hidden" value="%{property}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: no problem. just take some time and mark your previous questions with an accepted answer, if there isn't one suitable just mark the closest or answer it yourself so other people searching for the same problem will get some help